reading and visualizing raw images from Optris PI640
I have LWIR image files taken from Optris PI 640 camera. The files come with a .raw extension. I tried reading them in python and the np.shape I get is 999800800. However I'm unable to visualize it to make sense of it. According to the cam resolution 640x480, the image should be visualized but I cant reshape it as there is a remainder. Can anyone give some hint as to how I can visualize it? Whether there are different channels in the image? or some meta data?
